# Can the default PowerShell terminal keep a command history?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Is there a way to have PowerShell remember commands entered during the previous sessions? That is, after closing the window and opening it again, can PowerShell be setup to remember the commands?

Comment: A Powershell command window does not keep a log by default.  You should have to use a third-party command shell to get this functionality.

Comment: @Ramhound Darn, I was hoping it could take a history file, like Bash does.

Comment: Out of the box this feature does not exist.

Comment: If you need it to recall commands you use over and over why not use profiles? You can also look at using Start-Transcript.

Comment: @ShawnMelton How do you mean? My intention was to use profiles, but I don't see how I can automatically save commands.

Comment: Why would you automatically need to save them? Do you literally need to save the exact command, or the purpose of the command? If I issue a command that I find myself using a second time then I out that command in "my notebook" or profile for use again.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/07/01/perserving-command-history-across-sessions.aspx came across this from the architect behind Powershell. You would just need to train yourself around not tying exit or hitting the red x to close the window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows PowerShell in Windows 10 has this functionality by default.

The history file is located at `AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PSReadline\ConsoleHost_history.txt`.

Comment: Where is the history file?

Comment: @0fnt I've added the location to the answer.

Comment: 1) Isn't this only if you are using the 'PSReadline' module?   2) Is there a way to use Get-History (or '#<search term> [TAB]') against this file?

Answer (score 3):

**This answer applies only to older PowerShell versions. At least since ver. 5 PowerShell persists history to a file automatically**

With a little bit of scripting you could set this up, even without third party software.  I would recommend reading the help on Get-History, Add-History, and about_History.

As the help explains, you can use Get-History to get your current history and with a command such as `Get-History | Export-CliXml C:\History.CliXml` save it to a file.  Following that, you could import your history using the Add-History command.

(The Add-History help file actually explains how to do this in more detail.)

I would expect that it is possible to configure your environment to perform these actions automatically, although I would question the usefulness of such a setup.

Comment: +1, thanks. The functionality is all there. But this would be a bit too cumbersome. Just pressing the up arrow without having to use Add-History would be ideal.

Comment: I can't see an automated way to export the history on an exit.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I can't find a way to make the arrow keys work with the imported history (not sure why), but you might be able to use something from [this](https://lopsa.org/content/persistent-history-powershell) to help with automation.  Unfortunately it seems that it's extremely difficult to make any code execute when the x button is clicked; you have to actually type exit.

Comment: Check out http://www.github.com/lzybkr/PSReadline - it supports arrow keys with imported history.  V2 had a bug so that clicking on the x did not reliably run your exit handler, that bug was fixed in V3.

Comment: Orson Tyrell has a nice implementation of Mark's suggestion: http://orsontyrell.blogspot.co.at/2013/11/true-powershell-command-history.html