# How to make windows 8.1 command line save commands history?

Tags: windows-8, command-line, command-history

Exist a way to automatically save command history on windows 8.1 command line and have it available after close and open the command line program?

Comment: I was wondering something similar: http://superuser.com/questions/679816/can-the-default-powershell-terminal-keep-a-command-history

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with an addon.

Source [Is there a global, persistent CMD history?](https://serverfault.com/a/487339) answer by Robert Bak:

> Not natively but check out: http://mridgers.github.io/clink/ , makes
>   cmd.exe much more productive. Quoting features from the project page:
>
> ```
> Powerful Bash-like line editing from GNU's Readline library.
> Superior path completion (TAB).
> Paste from clipboard (Ctrl-V).
> Support for the completion of executables/commands, and environment variables.
> Undo/Redo (Ctrl-_ or Ctrl-X, Ctrl-U)
> Improved command line history.
> Persists across sessions.
> Searchable (Ctrl-R and Ctrl-S).
> History expansion (e.g. !!, !<string>, and !$).
> Scriptable completion using Lua.
> ```